# How do I check if a value exists in a Firebase DB based on another value

Tags: javascript, json, firebase-realtime-database

The following piece of code checks if ID **U1EL5623** exists.
I however need an extra condition.
It should return only true if also the fName is equal to **John**

Is there a way to check if the a value exists based on the value of another item?

**CODE**

```
ref.child("users").orderByChild("ID").equalTo("U1EL5623").once("value",snapshot => {
    const userData = snapshot.val();
    if (userData){
      console.log("exists!");
    }
});
```

**DATA**

```
{
  "users": {
    "-KKUmYgLYREWCnWeHCvO": {
      "fName": "Peter",
      "ID": "U1EL9SSUQ",
      "username": "peter01"
    },
    "-KKUmYgLYREWCnWeHCvO": {
      "fName": "John",
      "ID": "U1EP7532",
      "username": "john.doe"
    },
    "-UIgmYgLWDRWCnWeHCpF": {
      "fName": "Alex",
      "ID": "U1EL5623",
      "username": "Alex.JP"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you are getting the value you can loop through all of the results and their objects and then you can also check if the fName is equal to John like that:

```
ref.child("users").orderByChild("ID").equalTo("U1EL5623").once("value",snapshot => {
const userData = snapshot.val();
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
var childData = childSnapshot.val();
if (userData && childData.fName === 'John'){
  console.log("exists!");
}
```

});